# React: Best way to update self, but prevent children from updating?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a Drag-and-drop implementation (from scratch, not using a DND library), and wanted to limit the number of unnecessary updates during drag.

Dragging the "clone" (which is usually a copy of the original element, but can be an arbitrary placeholder) is achieved by updating a state on a container component (the "Clonetainer") and using that to apply a transform. However, it makes no sense to update the entire subtree during a move, since the only change is the coords of the container.

Here's my solution to that:

```
const ClonetainerRenderShield = React.createClass({
    shouldComponentUpdate: function (newProps) {
        return newProps.shouldUpdate;
    },
    render: function () {
        return this.props.children; // Simple pass-through
    }
});

const Clonetainer = React.createClass({
    componentWillReceiveProps: function (newProps) {
        // OR in any further properties that may indicate a move, versus a child update
        this.isMoveEvent = this.props.offset !== newProps.offset;
    },
    render: function () {
        const style = { transform: `translate(${this.props.offset.left}px,${this.props.offset.top}px)` };
        return <div className="clonetainer-div" style={style}>
            <ClonetainerRenderShield shouldUpdate={ !this.isMoveEvent }>
                { this.props.children }
            </ClonetainerRenderShield>
        </div>;
    }
});
```

(I won't go into the details on the rest of the DND system, except to say that mouse events from an upstream component feed the offset param to the Clonetainer.)

The solution I came up with for stopping the update involved determining whether the Clonetainer was triggered to update because of a move or some other reason (and setting `this.isMoveEvent` accordingly), then shimming a component between the Clonetainer and the children consisting of nothing more than a shouldComponentUpdate based upon a passed-in prop (`shouldUpdate`).

This works. I've tested it in a way that shows that it's updating when it ought to and not updating when it shouldn't, but it feels a bit like overkill to have a separate shim component in there simply to block updates from flowing downhill. Is there a way to indicate that a child component should not be updated from its previous state in `render`, without requiring the child component to include its own `shouldComponentUpdate` logic?

Comment: I think your approach is correct and the best one available. Another approach would be to manipulate directly the DOM node for the `Clonetainer` during drag

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change `componentWillReceiveProps` to `shouldComponentUpdate` in the `Clonetainer` component and cut out the middle man. `shouldComponentUpdate` takes two parameters, `(object nextProps, object nextState)` which you can use to compare agains `this.state` and `this.props`. Returning true will cause a re-render.

```
const Clonetainer = React.createClass({
    shouldComponentUpdate: function (nextProps, nextState) {
        // OR in any further properties that may indicate a move, versus a child update
        this.props.offset !== nextProps.offset;
    },
    render: function () {
        const style = { transform: `translate(${this.props.offset.left}px,${this.props.offset.top}px)` };
        return <div className="clonetainer-div" style={style}>
            { this.props.children }
        </div>;
    }
});
```

Comment: That wouldn't let me change the positioning on the Clonetainer, though, would it? The problem I had comes when the position of the Clonetainer needs to change (so it needs to re-render) but none of the contents' data has (so they should not). With shouldComponentUpdate, I'd expect you either get "all" (shouldComponentUpdate returns true and the entire tree gets rerendered) or "nothing" (shouldComponentUpdate returns false and nothing at all about it changes).